# Why does the palindrome function built on top of the Deque class doesn't work?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I created the following palindrome function using a Deque class.
The program should return *True* and *False*.
However, nothing is returned when I run the program.
Can anyone ascertain why?

```
class Deque:

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def add_front(self, item):
        
        self.items.insert(0, item)

    def add_rear(self, item):
        
        self.items.append(item)

    

def palindrome(word):
    lst1 = Deque()
    lst2 = Deque()

    [lst1.add_front(i) for i in word.lower()]
    [lst2.add_rear(i) for i in word.lower()]

    return lst1.items == lst2.items

palindrome('racecar')
palindrome('oranges')
```

Comment: Are you sure? Your code works for me in the console. Ok, found the problem: When you put this in one file nothing will happen, just wrap the palindrome-calls in a `print(palindrome(...))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of the palindrome function is a boolean, but in your code the function is just invoked without the result being used anywhere, thus the result is discarded and the program will just exit before outputting anything.  If you want to display the result on a terminal/console after running the code, wraps the palindrome function call in print.